# Accessing to server-side session variable ReactJS / expressJS

Tags: reactjs, express, express-session

I'm writing a simple CRUD with login app using Express as a backend and React as a frontend. In the backend, after user is logged in correctly, I create a session variable, where I store information about the user - and it works well.

In some places in the frontend, I want to know if user is authenticated or not (checking in the server session if `session.user` is set).

Is this a proper approach of verifying user's authentication in the frontend? Or is there a better way of verifying user's authentication in the frontend?

Here's my code where I'm setting session variable:

```
    module.exports = {
    login: function(req, res){

        const {email, password} = req.body;

        console.log(email, password);

        UserModel.authenticate(email, password, function(err, result){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }

            if (result.rows.length == 0){
                return res.status(404).send('Bad credentials');
            }

            req.session.user = result.rows[0];

            return res.sendStatus(200);

        });
    }
}
```